# 404 error. Flask can't find my static files

Tags: flask

I have my css file and bootstrap file inside css folder which is also inside static folder. My HTML is in templates folder.

static -> css -> theme.css and bootstrap.min.css

templates -> index.html

HTML

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I get the following error

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)

Also when I change something in theme.css the style doesn't change.

Comment: try adding ```type="text/css"``` to ```<link>```? Also add everything before ```href```

Comment: didn't work "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Comment: I did the same but didn't get any errors! try renaming all files and folders in your project and also force refresh the page (using CTRL+F5 on windows)